# SOASE 7DS - how to clear mines?

Tags: sins-of-a-solar-empire

Sort of a throwback here, but I was playing a few rounds of 7 Deadly Sins (still great) and as usual, the AI was throwing up piles of mines, taking over all of the tactical slots with 30 useless mines.

To clear them, I have to physically steer a heavy ship around and carefully blow them up.  Is there an automated, easier way to do this?  I was looking at the scout ships but I couldn't find much in the way of mine-clearing. Any tips?

Comment: if I remember correctly, scout ships make mines visible so they'll be auto targeted by your fleet if they're in range.

Comment: Oh is that how that works! I read about that ability but didn't put two and two together. Thanks.  Can't wait to get home from work ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Mines are a new defensive technology added in Entrenchment. The best way and pretty much the only way to get rid of mines is with a Scout Frigate. As long as a scout frigate is near a mine it will allow other ships to target and destroy them.

There are a multitude of different mines in which all of them can be found [here](http://sinsofasolarempire.wikia.com/wiki/Mines).

As long as your scout ship is in range of the mines other ships can blow them up.

Comment: I've tried this and it works exactly like I want it to. A pile of scouts clear out the mines automatically with no further input. Great :)